# Probability of Angela and Blake sit next to each other if 10 friends are randomly assigned seats?

Tags: probability, statistics

A group of 10 friends attend a concert together. I have found out that having 10 seats there are **10!** ways for the friends to be seated. But my question is how do i figure out the probability that 2 of those people being a couple are seated next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the couple as if they were one person, then you have $9!$ ways for them to sit, but of course, the couple can always switch seats, so at the end, you get $2\times9!$ ways.
So the probability that they sit together is $$\frac{2.9!}{10!}=0.2$$

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach, if you're comfortable with conditional probabilities: Imagine that Angela arrives first and sits in a random seat. Then Blake arrives and sits down in a random one of the nine remaining seats. What are his chances that his random seat is next to Angela? Well, $2/9$ because $2$ of the $9$ remaining seats are next to Angela, **except** if Angela  happened to sit in one of the two end seats, in which case there's only one seat next to hers and so Blake's chances of getting it are only $1/9$. Since there are two end seats and $8$ others, the probability of Angela getting an end seat is $2/10$, and the proability that she gets an interior seat is $8/10$.  So the probability that Blake gets a seat next to Angela is 
$$
\frac8{10}\cdot\frac29+\frac2{10}\cdot\frac19=\frac{18}{90}=
\frac15.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Add a person $0$ to the group and arrange the eleven persons around a circle. The $0$ marks the place where the circle then will be cut up into a row of the ten real persons. In the circular arrangement $A$ has two neighbors. The probability that $B$ is one of them is ${2\over10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Angela and Blake can sit next to each other in $18$ ways: they occupy seats 1 and 2, or seats 2 and 3, or ..., so there are $9$ possible pairs of seats next to each other, and they can fill those two seats in two ways, for a total of $2\cdot 9=18$ ways.

Then, after Angela and Blake have their two seats, there are $8!$ ways to seat the remaining $8$ people, so there are $18 \cdot 8!$ different ways to seat all $10$ friends where Angela and Blake end up sitting next to each other.

So, divide $18\cdot 8!$ by $10!$, and you'll have the probability they are sitting next to each other.

Comment: you have to divide $18\times 8!$ by $10!$

Comment: If you count the number of ways Angela and Blake can be seated together for the favorable cases, you have to divide by the number of ways Angela and Blake could be seated.

Comment: Alternatively there are $10*9$ ways Angela and Blake can sit (if we ignore everyone else).  And there are $18$ ways they can sit next to each other (if we ignore everyone else).  So divide $18$ by $90$.  Or if we *dont*  ignore everyone else there are $18*8!$ Angela and Blake and everyone else can sit with A and B together and we divide that by $10!$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of listing the choices counting the options as they come up.  And once selecting the options how many options remain for the of the choices.

Choice 1 for Angela and Blake sit next to each other:  Who sits to the left?  There are two choices; Angela or Blake.

Choice 2, once choice one is made who sits to the right: Well, there's one option.  Whoever's left.

Choice 3, of the 10 seats on which seat does the leftmost person sit.  Well seats $1.... 9$ have seats $2...10$ to the right of them but seat $10$ does not.  So the left most person may not sit in seat $10$ (because that leaves no-where for the rightmost of the pair to sit0.  So there are $9$ choices.

Choice 4, where does the right most of the pair sit.  S/he must sit immediately to the right if they are to sit together.  One option.

Choices 5-12: where does everyone else sit.  Well there are $8$ seats remaining for the third person, $7$ for the fourth and so on.  There are $8!$ ways for the remaining $8$ people to sit.

so the total number of ways for Angela and Blake to sit together is $2*1*9*1*8! = 18*8!$

And the total numbers of ways for people to sit whether or not Angela and Blake sit together is $10!$.

So the probability is $\frac {18*8!}{10!} = \frac {18*8!}{10*9*8!} = \frac {18}{10*9} = \frac {2*9}{10*9} = \frac 15$

I realize that was excrutiatingly spelled out but I wanted to impress how to think about how to solve these.

.... Alternative hard way....

Blake can sit in $10$ chairs.  Theres a $\frac 2{10}$ probability that he sits in an end seat.  If so, of the remaining $9$ students there is a $\frac 19$ probability that his neighbor is Angela.

On the other hand, If Blake is sitting in the middle there is a one in $\frac 19$ probability that his *left* neighbor is Angela.

If Blake's left neighbor is not Angela, there are $8$ remaining people and the probability of Blake's *right* neighbor is $\frac 18$.

So probability of Blake and Angela sitting next to each other is:

$\underbrace{\frac 2{10}}_{\text{Blake on end}}\underbrace{\frac 19}_{\text{Angela is neighbor}}+ \underbrace{\frac 8{10}}_{\text{Blake not on end}}\underbrace{\frac 19}_{\text{Angela is left neighbor}}+\underbrace{\frac 8{10}}_{\text{Blake not on end}}\underbrace{\frac 89}_{\text{Angela is not left neighbor}}\underbrace{\frac 18}_{\text{Angela is right neighbor}}=$

$\frac 15\frac 19 + \frac 45\frac 19 + \frac 45\frac 19=\frac 15\frac 19 + 2\cdot\frac 45\frac 19 = \frac 15$.